# Error with firestore: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to integrate Firestore into a vanilla JS project and I'm getting this error every time I try getDocs:

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.4.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

However, my device is connected to the Internet just fine and authentication is working with firebase, so I'm pretty sure it's at least connecting to my project. Any help is appreciated.